# pyinstaller but with one file keeping ans script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to build an .exe. I am using `built-in` libraries for `python-3.9.4` so there is nothing which could cause any further issues. But I did not find a way how to keep one from four files as `.py` script.

`qac.py` is my `__main__`, it uses two scripts from `qac_bin` folder.
The `qac_user_settings.py` is the one I need to keep as script. Is it even possible or am I in dead end?

[image: Structure]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, why you want to keep script as a separate file, but if you're importing "qac_user_seeting.py" in your main, pyinstaller will pack that together with main. You can use "scriptname" method of pyinstaller, to icnclude only specific files from your directory to be packed in to .exe

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html

Comment: The thing is that qac_user_settings.py is actually configuration file for the user, but in our company we have some curious devs who would most likely touch the logic script behind the configuration file. It would break it. I have to keep it untouchable for them. This is why.

Comment: If you need config file, then you can create it and import config to your main script. Anyways, with scriptname method of pyinstaller, you can choose which files are taken in to considaration, when building .exe